# Implement twitter bootstrap modal window call html

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I need to call a html data inside a twitter modal window from a .php file. How to call this function? This below script is inside a php file, i need to call this inside a modal window once we click the link. I am able to trigger the modal window but not the data.

```
<html xmlns=”http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml”>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=”Content-Type” content=”text/html; charset=utf-8″ />
<title><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></title>
<meta name=”robots” content=”noindex”/>
</head>
<body>
<div style=”"><?php echo $image; ?></div>
<?php echo $post->post_title; ?></b>
<p style=”float: left;”>Testing</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by putting your HTML inside a file called `remote.html`, then run this:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="remote.html" data-target="#modal">Click me</a>
```

Alternatively, you can insert HTML into the modal window using jquery, kind of like this:

```
$('.modal-button').click(function() {

    var myHTML = "[YOUR HTML]";
    $('.modal-body').html(myHTML);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

what you want is to display the image and title data inside the modal right?

```
<div>
<div id="image"></div>
<span id="myTitle"></span></b>
<p style=”float: left;”>Testing</p>
</div>
```

Place this content inside modal and fetch the image and title data through an ajax call

```
  $(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Fetch.php",//give the path of the php file or the function
                    data: '{ "query": ' + data + ' }',//place the query data
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        AjaxSucceeded(msg);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert("Failure");
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("Error " + jqXHR + " " + textStatus.responseText + " " + errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            });

AjaxSucceeded(msg){
//replace the div with the image and the title
$(#image).innerHTML=msg.Image;
$(#myTitle).innerHTML=msg.Title;
}
```

Cheers!!!

Comment: @amit kumar not working :( can i PM you so that you can test my site.

Comment: yeah sure amitcse@ymail.com is my email-id. Feel free to discuss. I will surely get back to you tomorrow.